# Attempting to edit/update a boolean, something is not working

Tags: java, keyboard, boolean

First, I will post my code - more explanation at the bottom.

Here's the first class, `Player`.

```
package main;
import main.Screen;
import main.Keyboard;

public class Player extends Mob {

    private Keyboard input = new Keyboard();

    private int color = 0x0066CC;
    private int xPos = 50;
    private int yPos = 50;
    private int xSize = 10;
    private int ySize = 10;

    public Player() {

    }

    public void render(Screen screen) {
        screen.addSquare(xPos, yPos, xSize, ySize, color);
        return;
    }

    public void update() {
        this.input.update();
        if (input.up == true) { 
            xPos = xPos + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("xPos is " + xPos);
    }   
}
```

Here's the second class, `Keyboard`.

```
package main;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];

    public boolean up, down, left, right;

    public  void update() {
        System.out.println("Reached 3");
        up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];

        System.out.println("up " + up + ", down " + down + ", left " + left + ", right " + right);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

There we have it. The issue lies with the Keyboard class - no matter what I do, it is incapable of updating the booleans according to the keys.

(The `Player.update()` method is called as often as the computer can, it's not an error with that being updated.)

I'll be happy to clarify anything needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting a print call in the keyPressed/release methods to ensure that they're getting called. Also consider storing the players fields in a [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) instead of inividually

Comment: In other code you're not showing, are you registering the Keyboard class with some control (e.g. somecontrol.addKeyListener(input))?  You have to do that somwhere so that Keyboard knows what to listen to.

Comment: Your Keyboard class implements KeyListener, but are you actually adding it to anything? It doesn't seem you are doing so anywhere in the code you have posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `boolean` values are not being changed because the `KeyListener` was not registered in the `Player` class.

If you take a look at the [KeyEvent API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) you will find the following explanation regarding key events:

> This low-level event is generated by a component object (such as a
>   text field) when a key is pressed, released, or typed. The event is
>   passed to every KeyListener or KeyAdapter object which registered to
>   receive such events using the component's addKeyListener method.
>   (KeyAdapter objects implement the KeyListener interface.) Each such
>   listener object gets this KeyEvent when the event occurs.

Basically it states that in order for these key events take place, you do need to register them using either `KeyListener or`KeyAdapter`.

In this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt.event/KeyEventgetKeyCode.htm) you will find a nice usage of these events.